# How to detect if the user views a page's javascript or clicks on inspect in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, web-inspector

I would like to be able to detect if the user inspects anything on a web page, i.e., clicks on inspect.  I would like to do this to warn the user not to do it - as I want to prevent students from trying to hack the javascript code and end up cheating on an exam.

Thanks.

(A chrome only solution is ok, but would prefer something more general.)

Comment: If you don't want students to cheat then use an API to validate answers on the server, not on the client.

Comment: it's called 'security by obscurity'. Don't do this or you'd get hacked. :)

Comment: I am not storing anything on the front-end, but don't want them to see the calls being made, etc.  This is just extra added protection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant fully protect it unless you store the answers on the server-side as mentioned.

However, you can disable right-click in the browser.  You could also make the webpage play an alert sound to warn you during an exam of who is doing it.

Add this to your body tag:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

And add this script:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

Additionally, you could detect keypress such as F12 and play a sound if someone is trying to access the dev console:

```
http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/
```

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I, Ctrl+Shift+C, F12, etc.

Comment: Good point, you could detect these as well.  You can still open it from the File menu, but I would bet a lot of people use the keyboard shortcut and if you play a sound during the exam and they aren't expecting it, will identify those using them.

Comment: Well, I think we should rely on inner devtools behavior rather than clicks and keyboard. :)

Comment: Measuring the time to write to the console is a novel solution to detect it! May work for this situation, long term you would want to keep validating the code against a specific browser and version. Cool...

Comment: I've just tried it and it failed actually. :) Mostly because of my notebook has dynamic CPU frequency.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you shouldn't rely on that for actually protecting your information.

But for the question:

Both http://blog.guya.net/2014/06/20/how-to-know-when-chrome-console-is-open/ and https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect are good enough.

Comment: Excellent references.  Thanks.